# Using GooglePay with Stripe Gateway

Tags: stripe-payments, google-pay

I'm having a problem configuring GooglePay using the Stripe gateway because it says the "stripe:publishablekey" is missing after I click the "Continue" button in the GooglePay payment sheet.

In my code, this occurs in the loadPaymentData(paymentDataRequest) line which displays the GooglePay payment sheet and is supposed to return a response(with a payment token) after finishing according to [this](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/client#loadPaymentData). But is not happening because of the error I mentioned above.

In my paymentDataRequest object, I already have the "stripe:publishablekey" field and I don't get why it's saying that it's [missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpklJ.png).

I've already tried copying the field that is in the [Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/tutorial#tokenization) from Google where the "k" in the stripe:publishablekey is supposed to be capitalised like this "K" but it only gives another error message that says "stripe:publishableKey" is an invalid field.

Sorry for my bad english and also this is my first time asking a question in stackoverflow.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure what the problem that you're facing is, however, I was able to get it to work with the following: https://jsfiddle.net/u3snqdwm/

FYI, I'm using `stripe:publishableKey` with a capitalized `K`.

```js
tokenizationSpecification: {
  type: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
  parameters: {
    'gateway': 'stripe',
    'stripe:version': '2018-10-31',
    'stripe:publishableKey': 'pk_test_MNKMwKAvgdo2yKOhIeCOE6MZ00yS3mWShu'
  },
},
```

Comment: Hi, I think I've figured out the problem. It seems like I was using the wrong key(i think i was using the secret key) which is not a publishable key from Stripe. I noticed that the key you're using has the prefix "pk_test". So I tried using that with the "stripe:publishableKey" field and it's now working perfectly fine. Thanks @Soc